# Customize height of n cells in UITableView, but not all the same

Tags: iphone, uitableview

thanks to the folks here I already learned quite a lot on my way to a cool iPhone App I am working on. However, I was wondering if anyone found out how to manipulate a UITableView, so that a cell (any or, if that is not possible, it could only be the selected one) can have a different height.

I know I can use something like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 70;
```

}*/

To modify the whole TableView. But how would I address this to a single, specific cell?

The final goal is to achieve a "OS X dock"-like zoom effect when scrolling through a table...

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,
J*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that you're citing there in your question is exactly the method you want to use. The code you posted always returns a fixed value. But the `indexPath` parameter is there so that you can use that in whatever conditional processing you might want to do. For example, determine if that row is selected, and return a different height.

You'll also want to take care that the cell you return from [`-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) matches this height.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `indexPath` row and section to determine and return the height for the cell.

All of the methods related to `UITableViewController` give you an `indexPath` that will correspond to the cell when asking for specific information. For example, when asking for the actual cell to return:
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

What to do when a cell was selected:
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Height of the cell:
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And several others. Check out a `UITableViewController` tutorial to get the hang of how it works as a `delegate` and a `dataSource` for a `UITableView`.

Here is a good one: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/

Comment: Hi mjdth,

thanks a lot ... I guess getting used to the general approach of Cocoa and OOP is my issue here. I will try to find that how to do smthg with NSIndexPath and the method to set the height. Thanks for the link to the tutorial.